# Cómo puedo hacer un backup a MongoDB si no puedo iniciar el servidor mongod en windows

Tags: mongodb, mongod

Al intentar abrir mi servidor mongod en mi pc no me inicia y me sale excepción no encontrada, en muchas partes dicen que hay que desinstalar y volver a instalar el programa pero no puedo perder las bases de datos y las colecciones, la cuestión es que está la carpeta data y dentro de esta está la de DB y LOG,  me gustaría saber si copiando esa carpeta puedo recuperar esa información después al instalar el programa.
Muchas gracias

Comment: debería poder levantar los mismos datos, para hacer una prueba podes montar una vm, instalar la misma versión, detener el servicio y copiar la carpeta data, reiniciar el servicio y ver que pasa (hacer snapshots/copia del filesystem/carpetas es una de las formas de backup)

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 0):

Sigue los siguientes pasos

- Reinstala la misma versión de MongoDB qe tenías anteriormente.
- Asegúrate que tu `mongod.cfg` apunta a las carpetas de datos y log que tenías anteriormente
- Inicia el proceso o servicio.

Deberías poder levantar `mongod` sin problemas. Si obtienes algún error actualiza tu pregunta con el error para poder ayudarte.